# Android Studio 3.0.1. Very slow work on android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

Windows 10 (64bit)

Processor: Intel Core 3.10 GHz

RAM 8GB

Android Studio 3.0.1

Java 1.8

Gradle 4.1.

In **c:\Users\myuser.AndroidStudio3.0\studio64.exe.vmoptions**

```
# custom Android Studio VM options, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html
-server
-Xms256m
-Xmx3g
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-da
```

In **gradle.properties**:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

When I run my application on device ---> all work fine. Nice.

But when I start on this emulator (**API 27**):
[image: avd]

all work **very slow**.

Here my task manager (when emulator was started).

[image: taskmanager]

As you can is available ONLY 638 MB

How I can fix this?

Comment: I have same problem. Need solution for AS 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Check `sdk` is it uses **`Intel HAXM`**!

[image: http://joxi.ru/Vm6oZpbcxWZZN2]

and add more `RAM` and `VM Heap`, *`Emulated Performance Graphics`* is **`Automatic`**

[image]

Or use template device - with *high-performance* in **API 27** case - like Google Pixel series.

Comment: `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` is check on. So it's not help. It's slow with ALL emulators (not only API 27)

Comment: First, you need to increase RAM 2048, VM head 256. And check, is you using an Intel x86 image of emulator! Your PC configuration is not too bad to slow ALL emulators (I think, it's not the main problem).

Comment: Has anyone solve this issue? I tried the suggested solutions, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I have this very same problem for two weeks now

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by reinstalling Android Emulator from SDK tool section. Apart from it, also reinstall HAXM with 4GB memory. Then create a new AVD with 2GB RAM and 512 MB VM space.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing help. Only after upgrade RAM to 16 GB the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the possible solutions available, it was very slow with 12 GB RAM, finally I wiped the emulator data,

**AVD Manager - > Choose "Wipe data" option in the list of emulators drop down menu option.**

It works!